# Sort array by member variables

Tags: c#-4.0

If I have a class like this

```
public class Character
{
    public int speed = 0;
    //Other code...
}
```

And another class which takes *Characters* for input, **how can I sort the characters based on their speed?**

I'm currently using an ArrayList to store the characters.

This is a mockup of what I'm looking for:
**Before**
character 1... speed 4
character 2... speed 9
character 3... speed 1
**After**
character 3... speed 1
character 1... speed 4
character 2... speed 9

Comment: Check out [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx).

Comment: Look into using LINQ and OrderBy. And ditch ArrayList - we've had generic collections for nearly 9 years now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
var orderedBySpeed = characters.OrderBy(c => c.Speed);
```

However, use a generic `List<Character>` instead of an `ArrayList`. If you insist on an `ArrayList`(there's no reason to do so):

```
var orderedBySpeed = characters.Cast<Character>().OrderBy(c => c.speed);
```

Comment: I don't insist on ArrayLists. I've already been using generic Lists, but I like ArrayLists whenever it doesn't matter. Blame Java.

Comment: @Stopforgettingmyaccounts...: java `ArrayLists` are C# `List<T>` since they are generic. In C# they are just a collection of objects. But even if you need to store objects you should use a `List<object>` instead.